# Refresh Div from Within Separate iFrame in JavaScript/ASP.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have an iFrame that contains an upload form. Upon successful upload, I need the controller (or the iFrame view) to refresh a DIV that's outside the iFrame. How to accomplish this? I tried this in the iFrame view, which gets reloaded after upload, and nothing happens:

```
 document.getElementById('reportContainer').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: do you control the outside code?

Comment: yes I do  @Sagivb.g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the code of the parent then i recommend to go for a pub / sub solution.

The `iFrame` will trigger a custom event to the parent.
The parent will act on the target `div` when the event is triggered.

`iFrame` code:

```
var myCustomEventData = { foo: 'bar' } // optional if you need to pass data
var myEvent = new CustomEvent('myEvent', { detail: myCustomEventData });
window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

Parent code:

```
window.document.addEventListener('myEvent', handleEvent, false)
function handleEvent(e) {
  console.log(e.detail) // logs: {foo: 'bar'}
}
```

Comment: This does allow the iFrame to communicate with its parent page (which contains the DIV), unfortunately with the following on parent page, the DIV doesn't render at all. Note that this DIV contains a Power BI Embedded report, if that matters.     `function handleEvent(e) {
        console.log(e.detail) // logs: {foo: 'bar'}
  
        $("#reportContainer").load(location.href + " #reportContainer>*", "");}`

Comment: well then this is not related to your original question then, your problem is not with the `iframe` but with rendering an element.